# useState vs. useEffect - setting initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have two basic questions about React:

1. In order to assign an initial empty value to a piece of state (let's say `player`) in a functional component, are the following two approaches the same or are they different in some way?

#### Approach A:

```
const [player, setPlayer] = useState({})
```

#### Approach B:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setPlayer({})
}, []);
```

2. When I browse to a `player`, the page is eventually updated with values coming from the global store so I need to avoid showing the values of the previous player while the current one is still loading. What is the best way to go about this?

---

Please let me know if you need more background information in order to help. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When assigning initial value directly in `useState(initialData)` you are making that state available in the very first render.

On the other hand, if you are setting the initial value in a `useEffect` hook, it will be set on mount, **but** after the very first render.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    setPlayer(initialData)
}, [])
```

If the state variable is important also for the *first render*, then you should use the first approach. It is also shorter to write and makes more sense.

[image]

### Example:

if you open your *devtools* when running this example, the `debugger` will pause inside the `useEffect` and you will see nothing will be rendered ("mount" phase), which might not be desirable. If you were to edit the code and write `useState(initialData)`, you would see the first render did include the correct state when the (when `debugger` pauses code execution).

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React

const App = ({initialData}) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('') 

  useEffect(() => {
    debugger; // at this point, the component has already been rendered
    setValue(initialData)
  }, [])

  return value
}

ReactDOM.render(<App initialData={''} />, root)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It is crystal clear now.